# What is correct between 'call A as B' and 'call A B'?

Tags: verbs, as

> In this section, we consider a cellular network that consists of one base station (BS) and many user equipments (UEs). We call the BS and all the UEs as the nodes.

I learned that the verb 'call' is used like "I call him a superman." Do I have to delete 'as'?

However, the following sentence looks very awkward.

> We call the BS and all the UEs the nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Call as" is not idiomatic. Deleting "as" but retaining "the" results in a grammatical construction, but I agree that it sounds a bit awkward. "We call the BS and all the EUs nodes" is more idiomatic. I point out that even the last version is possibly open to misinterpretation. I cannot be positive that what is meant is "We call the BS and each EU a node" or "We call the BS a node and the EUs collectively a node." I am 99% sure that the former is meant, but why not avoid any possibility for misinterpretation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use "as" with "call".

> We call her "The Tiger Lady"

"As" is required with a different verb, like "refer to":

> We refer to her as "The Tiger Lady".

That being said, your sentence is confusing.  Might I suggest:

> The BS and all the UEs are collectively called the "nodes" of the network.

Comment: I think it's just as good to say ***The BS and the UEs are called "nodes."***

Comment: I cannot write double quotation marks in my paper. The third one is very nice. Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask one more thing??? I want to explain the following sets.

* A = {(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)}
* B = {(x4,y4), (x5,y5), (x6,y6)}
* C = {(x7,y7), (x6,y6), (x9,y9)}
Which is correct?
> (A set / Sets) of (the locations / the location / locations / location) of the rabbits, the lions, and the tigers are denoted by A, B, and C.

Comment: "The locations of x, y, and z ... are denoted by A, B, and C respectively" avoids any possible confusion.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Thank you for answer! In my case, I have to mention that they are sets because I am writing a Math paper.